# When does -[UIWebPDFView _recreateUIPDFDocument] gets called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, didreceivememorywarning

I have a crash related to -[UIWebPDFView _recreateUIPDFDocument]. The crash occurs after a Memory Warning message which calls -[UIWebPDFViewHandler didReceiveMemoryWarning:] which in turn calls -[UIWebPDFView _recreateUIPDFDocument] which crashes the app.
I was trying to recreate this crash but couldn't.

How can I do that?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you try a really heavy-duty PDF: one with lots of paths in it, like a subway or city map.